# Need help with mathematical induction on transitive relation problem.

Tags: logic, induction, relations

Problem as follows:

Let $R$ be a transitive relation. Let $aR^nb$ for $n \geqslant 1$, mean that there is a sequence of tuples: 
$$
⟨a_0,a_1⟩,⟨a_1,a_2⟩, \ldots , ⟨a_{n-1},a_n⟩
$$
from $R$ such that $a_0 = a$ and $a_n = b$. Prove the following: "If $a R^n b$, then $a R b$" for all natural numbers $n \geqslant 1$, by mathematical induction.

Now, I understand why this assertion would be true, it's just proving it with mathematical induction that's giving me problems. (Check for $n = 1$, assume $n = k$, prove $n = k+1$ etc.)

Comment: In Set Theory  a binary relation $R$ on a set $ S$ is some (any) subset of $S\times S,$ and $aRb$ means $\langle a,b \rangle\in R$. But if $S=\Bbb N$ and $ R$ is $<, $ nobody wants to write $\langle 1,2 \rangle \in <$    for $1<2.$.... BTW the method, in the first answer posted, of reducing the inductive step $S(n)\implies S(n+1)$ to the statement $S(2)$, is  widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a\mathop{R^n}b\implies a\mathop Rb$. Then, if $a\mathop{R^{n+1}}b$, there is a $c$ such that $a\mathop Rc$ and that $c\mathop{R^n}b$. But $c\mathop{R^n}b\implies c\mathop Rb$. So, $a\mathop Rc$ and $c\mathop Rb$. Since $R$ is transitive, $a\mathop Rb$.